# Exception during generic container clearing, C++

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I am having problems with clearing of the generic container. In carrying out the function clear() the program fails.

Base class:

```
//Generic container
template <class Item>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};

template <class Item>
class GContainer
{
protected:
            typename TList <Item>::Type items;

public:
            GContainer() : items (0) {}
    virtual ~GContainer() = 0;

public:
            typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator begin() { return items.begin(); }
            typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator end() { return items.end(); }
...
};
```

Derived class:

```
//Generic container for points
template <class Point>
class ContPoints : public GContainer <Point>
{
public:
    void clear();
            ...
};

//Specialization
template <class Point>
class ContPoints <Point *> : public GContainer <Point>
{
public:
    void clear();
            ...
};
```

Implementation of the method clear()

```
template <class Point>
void ContPoints <Point *>::clear()
{
        for ( typename TItemsList <Point>::Type ::iterator i_items = items.begin(); i_items != items.end(); ++i_items )
        {
                //Delete each node
                if ( &(i_items) != NULL )
                {
                          delete * i_items //Compile error, not usable, why ???
                          delete &*i_items; //Usable, but exception
                  *i_items) = 0; //Than exception
                }
        }
        items.clear(); //vector clear
}
```

Suprisingly:

A] I am not able to delete *i_items...

```
delete *i_items; //Error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'Point<T>' to 'void *
```

B] I am able to delete only &*i_items...

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  ContPoints <Point<double> *> pll;
  pll.push_back (new Point <double>(0,0));
  pll.push_back (new Point <double>(10,10));
  pll.clear(); //Exception
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

`delete &*i_items;` should be `delete *i_items;`. You don't want to delete the address of the pointer, you want to delete the pointer! I don't see a reason for the following line (`*i_items) = 0; //Exception`) at all.

Finally, why insert points by pointer? Just insert the actual points and use `std::vector` instead. If you want containers which automatically `delete` their contents, consider [boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: But delete i_items results in error Error C2440 (VS 2010), see above... I do not like boost, I prefer a solution without boost :-)

Comment: @Woody: That error is only thrown on a bad type cast. I don't see any type casting going on here.... post your actual code please. As for without boost, I don't quite understand what's not to like given that you're merely reimplementing a boost library...

Comment: I thought, that in std::vector <Item> Type Item can represent both object and pointer (i.e. Item = Object and Item = *Object ). But it is a wrong assumption...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from this

```
template <class Point>
class ContPoints <Point *> : public GContainer <Point>
```

the `GContainer` is storing instances of `Point` by value, not pointers to `Point`.

This is confirmed by the error message: cannot convert a `Point<T>` to a pointer.

Comment: It means that in std::vector <Item> Type; Item can not be a pointer?

Comment: You inherited from a base class that defined it as `Point`, so the Type is `std::vector<Point>`, not the specialization of `Point*`

Comment: I supposed that Item could represent both object and pointer (i.e. Item = Object and Item = *Object )...

Comment: So I have to create specialization  GContainer <Item*> ?

Comment: @Woody: You could try inheriting from `GContainer<Point*>` to get a `vector<Point*>`. Whether you need to specialize anything depends on what you want those classes to do.

Comment: You mean class ContPoints <Point *> : public GContainer <Point*> ?